# pushState reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was attempting to follow the example used here: http://html5.gingerhost.com/
Instead of using JSON, I decided to use jQuery's .load() instead,

Here's my code:

```
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            $('img#logo').stop().hide().fadeIn( "slow" );

            href = $(this).attr("href");
            loadContent(href);
            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();         
        });

        // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
            loadContent(location.pathname);
        };
    });

    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $('#load').load( url + " #load2").stop().hide().fadeIn( 'slow' );   
    }
```

The example's loadContent function:

```
        function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $.getJSON("content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
                // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);
                });
                $("#loading").hide();
            });

        // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');

    }
```

HTML:

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>Andy Simon</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>                   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="top">  
        <div id="logo">
            <div>
            <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="logo1.png" /></a><span id="logo_text">simon</span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">  
            <a class="nav_link" id="work" href="work.html"> work . </a> 
            <a class="nav_link" id="work" href="work.html"> about . </a>
            <a class="nav_link" id="work" href="contact.html"> contact </a>                 
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div id ="middle">

        <div id="load">
            <div id="load2">
                home home andy pandy home home home
            </div>                      
        </div>  

    </div>  

    <div id="foot">     
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

When I click on a link, the page reloads, which is what I'm trying to prevent. I thought my e.preventDefault() would stop that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: May be some error occurs  and `preventDefault` does not executing because of it. Try using something like firebug console with "do not clean" (or like that) option switched on. It will show you errors in JS made on your page

Answer (score 0):

You can put a 'return false;' at your js code to prevent it to upload:

```
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('img#logo').stop().hide().fadeIn( "slow" );

        href = $(this).attr("href");
        loadContent(href);
        // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
        history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Tried it, but it is still reloading the page.

Comment: Edited my post with html included